# php -- is a file on a local or networked file system?

Tags: php, sqlite, filesystems, stat, flock

How can I find out, from a php-language program, whether a particular file is on a local file system (ext, NTFS, etc) or on a network-attached file system (nfs, smb, cifs) with bad advisory locking sematics?

In raw UNIXish system calls, the statfs system call would do that. But php doesn't have it.

I'm using SQLite3, and it works less-than-perfectly on networked file systems. I'd like to warn my users about that. Is there a clean way to do it? On just Linux? On Linux, MacOS, Windows, and FreeBSD?

Comment: Honestly I'd just drop a note in the docs and move on. Especially if you're looking to cover windows as well.

Comment: I get your point, for sure, and I'm tempted. This is a plugin for caching for WordPress users on budget hosting services, so I'm hoping to give people as much help as I reasonably can.